Как освободить BitmapImage?
Я при нажатии на кнопки меняю картинки
 /// <summary>
  /// Меняет картинки
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="index"></param>
  private void SetImageSource(int index)
  {
      Uri imageUri = new Uri(allFile[ index ], UriKind.Absolute);
      BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
      bitmap.BeginInit();
      bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
      bitmap.UriSource = imageUri;
      bitmap.EndInit();
      BorderImageBrush.ImageSource = bitmap;
      bitmap = null;
  }

Как мне освободить память от старого бипмапа ?
Память постоянно получается растёт когда листаю картинки
Останавливается примерно на 400


Хм, а зачем вам тут вообще битмап? У вас самая простейшая задача, которая решается простыми привязками, разве нет?

@EvgeniyZ, при перетаскивании папки конвертируются картинки в указанном расположении. Картинка открывается в этом расположении, и можно листать картинки.

Ну тем более, если картинки на диске, то вам достаточно работы с путями. Условно говоря, у вас должно быть свойство public string ImagePath { get; set; } (с INPC), далее вы к нему привязываетесь <Image Source = "{Binding ImagePath}" />, ну а дальше просто задаете нужный путь при смене ImagePath = $"C:\Folder\{index}.png";, ну и как бы... Все, WPF дальше сделает все за вас, создав нужные объекты и сам в нужное время их удалит. Так повторю вопрос: Почему не используются привязки?

А там не просто Image.
А сам цвет задний бордера
<Border Margin="10,20,10,0" CornerRadius="10">       <Border.Background>           <ImageBrush x:Name="BorderImageBrush" Stretch="Uniform"/>       </Border.Background>   </Border>

Если это ради закругления, то тоже странное решение. У вас должно быть <Border><Image/></Border>, ну а если нужно закругление изображению, то задайте ему маску.

ImageBrush.ImageSource точно также привязать к строке, содержайщей путь к картинке. Используйте привязки. А так, ничего необычного в использовании памяти нет. У вас нет проблемы с этим. Сборщик мусора удалит лишнее, как решит что пора. Кстати, на графике видно частую работу сборщика, но дело явно не в картинках, а где-то в другом месте. Возможно цикл какой-нибудь постоянно работает и мусорит. Но сам по себе график выглядит совершенно нормально.
